# Few css style properties not being applied on production

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet, durandal, hottowel

I have a hot towel SPA application in which I am using breeze for styling along with some custom css.
The sequence in which I am including the style files is as below:

```
    bundles.Add(
          new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include("~/Content/durandal.css")
            .Include("~/Content/toastr.css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
            .Include("~/Content/app.css")
          );
```

I have applied few styles to body element in app.css:

```
body {
   font-size: 18px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1100px;
   height:1200px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

When I inspect the body css in local and prodcution, I see that in production, the max-width and height properties are not being applied.
What could be the reason for the css to work in local and not in production ?

Comment: There may be a stylesheet somewhere in production that isn't on your local machine or vice versa. If the former, adding !important after the styles and before the semicolons will fix it.
Example: max-width:1100px!important;
This overrides other styles.

Comment: My ignorance. The css files did differ. Thank you.